# allow external users to access shared files using one-time access code instead of login, is this supported/possbile

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users, external-sharing

We have a SharePoint modern communication site >> and using a site admin >> i shared a file with external user >> by selecting the file >> click on Manage Access >> Advanced >> stop sharing the permission >> add the external user with contribute permission.

Then the external user will get an email >> click on the file link inside the email >> login using Personal Microsoft account Or Organizational account.

now my question is if we can force the access to the file to be done by sending a one-time code to the external user email >> enter the code >> access the file.. is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be achieved. You need to enable Microsoft SharePoint integration with **Azure AD B2B** first.

[Microsoft official article：](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-azureb2b-integration)

**Azure AD B2B provides authentication and management of guests. Authentication happens via one-time passcode when they don't already have a work or school account or a Microsoft account.**